# subdomain with www solve with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with my subdomains. Normally every uses this kind of format: subdomain.domain.com and if this is entered there is no problem. When a user inputs www.subdomain.domain.com, the site doesn't work. I asked our hosting-support and they said I had to fix it with the .htaccess but I can't seem to find anything.

I found this but that is just for the domain and not for a subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.prosoccerdata\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prosoccerdata.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would take care of both main as well as sub-domains.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```